# How to interpret a GDB backtrace in order to determine a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am in an entry level programming class. I understand that segmentation faults are due to an error in memory storage somewhere along the way. The program I wrote is supposed to take a file given to us that is in code and contains the instructions to decode it and then print the decoded message.

We have several test cases and my code runs for some of them, but not for the last one. I learned about GDB for debugging for the first time today and used backtrace full to try and source the error, but I'm not totally sure how to interpret what it gave me.

This is the code that I wrote.
**edited code out

When I did a backtrace, this is what it told me.

```
   #2  0x0000000000401523 in main () at main.cpp:42
    second = 61 '='
    third = 72 'H'
    msg = 0x606308
    i = 8
    chars = ""
    first = 90 'Z'
    numMess = 8
    out = <incomplete type>
    name = "input4.txt"
    in = <incomplete type>
    arr = "IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGH"
```

I don't know what the backtrace is telling me and I'm unsure of what to do with that information to discover and fix my error.

Comment: If you used `std::vector` instead of `new[ ]`, you would have had a chance without using gdb to discover the error.  Instead of `Messages *msg; msg = new Messages[numMess];` you could have done: `std::vector<Messages> msg(numMess);`, and then use `vector::at()` to detect out-of-bounds accesses.

Comment: How do the two compare? We haven't discussed std::vector in class before.

Comment: Note that i = 8 and numMess = 8. A `for` loop does exit on conditional in the third part, only the second.

Comment: @jgwentworth -- A vector uses the same syntax to access elements -- it is practically no different to the code you posted now (except for the declaration).  However `std::vector` has *additional* functions to test for out-of-bounds access.  If you changed to using `at()` instead of `[ ]`, you will get a `std::out_of_range` exception, not a seg fault and a gdb stacktrace to figure out.  As to your class, get a new teacher if they're teaching `new []` and `delete []` to create dynamic arrays in C++.

Comment: @jgwentworth `for (chars; std::getline(in, chars); i < numMess)` what is the "stop" condition in that `for` loop?  Or what is the condition that keeps that loop running?  Given that info, it should be simple to see how things can blow up.  What if the file has 1000 lines in it, and I am a prankster and input `numMess` to be 10?

Comment: Unfortunately, my university is not known for a great COSC department. I would really like to be really good at this but it seems it will be a learn on my own type journey. 

I changed that segment but I'm not sure if I implemented it correctly. Do I need to cout vector::at() or is it a function on its own? The error I received was 'used without template parameters.'

Comment: @jgwentworth Instead of `msg[i]` or similar, use `msg.at(i)` once `msg` has been changed to a `std::vector<Messages> msg(numMess);`.

Answer (score 0):

The hints from the trace are

```
i = 8
chars = ""
numMess = 8
```

`i` equals `numMess` and `chars` is empty.

Why does this matter? Looking at where `numMess` comes from, we see it's used to size the dynamic array pointed at by `msg` and `msg` is later indexed by `i`. when `i` equals `numMess`, `msg[i]` is out of bounds.

So how did this happen?

```
string chars;
getline(in, chars); // this doesn't make much sense. Reconsider it
for (chars; std::getline(in, chars); i < numMess) {
```

Here's where things went wrong. A for loop should look something like

```
for (initializer ; exit condition ; iterator to advance the loop)
```

but

```
for (chars; // does nothing. Compiler may be warning you
     std::getline(in, chars); // loop exits on failed read
     i < numMess) { // does nothing to advance the loop
```

Nothing in here prevents `i` from exceeding `numMess` because `i < numMess` is not being used as an exit condition. Right, but why doesn't `std::getline(in, chars);` kick out of the loop when it hits the end of the file? Empty line at the end of the file. `chars` was successfully set to an empty string.

```
for ( ; // nothing happening here
     i < numMess and std::getline(in, chars) ;
     ++i) { // and remove the ++i from the end of the loop.
```

Gets you out of the current predicament and might give you a program that does what you want. Haven't tested it.

But what if there is a mistake in the file and the file exits before reaching `numMess`? This is the sort of stuff PaulMckenzie is getting at. You're better off not trusting `numMess` at all and going with something more like

```
int numMess = 0;
in >> numMess; // not that we care
vector<Messages> msg;

//read file
int i = 0;
string chars;
while (std::getline(in, chars)) { // get each line. Note this gets the empty line, too
    Messages temp; // make a temporary for storage

    temp.messageNum = i + 1;
    temp.codedMessage = chars;


    //decode file
    for (char &j : chars) {
        if (j - 'A' >= 0 && j - 'A' < 26)
            j = arr[j - 'A'];
    }
    temp.decodedMessage = chars;
    msg.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: After making that change, I now get two compiling errors. One is that in 'msg' is not declared in the scope in the print segment 'out << Message Num: " << msg[i].messageNum << end;'. The other is that numMess was not declared in the last for loop. I'm a little confused on how changing the earlier for loop conditions affected them in this way.   

  I also had a question about the exist condition, is "and" something you can use in all code? We've only been taught to use "&&", do they work the same way?

Comment: Reverse the test in the loop.  It is more efficient to test for `i < numMess` first, since testing for `std::getline` returning 0 requires a file read.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie Good point. @jgwentworth nothing I suggested that you change in your code should have resulted in `msg` not being out of scope. [`and` is identical to `&&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative)

Comment: I still get the same errors in compiling telling me that numMess and msg are not defined in the scope. I thought that they were global since I declared them outside of the loops, but do they need to me declared again?

Comment: I'd need to see the current state of your code to tell you what's wrong. I pasted my modification into the code in your question and receive no errors.

Comment: I got it to work actually! I used my original code but both of your notes on the problem with the for loop and I put i++ at the end of the second for loop and i < numMess in the middle of the for loop. Thank you so much for your detailed explanations!